# typeahead.js binding to template issue

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, hogan.js

I am binding my typeahead for users images to hogan template and the code actually works fine but I am getting errors in console as it tries to get a resource: localhost:####/%7B%7BuserBlankImgUrl%7D%7D

The only thing that make sense is that it is trying to bind to the template value instead of waiting for a value.

Full disclosure: My app is using DurandalJS and knockoutJS pretty heavily but I tried to just show the relevant code below.  I will include more based on suggestions.

Template:

```
<img class="quarc-avatar-list-item" src="{{userBlankImgUrl}}" />
```

JS:

```
    self.userImgUrl = ko.computed(function () {
        return avatar.fromGravatar(self.email(), self.gender());
    });
```

Other things I have tried include:

1. Wrapping the template in null checks so doesn't try and bind.
2. When I remove the template hmtl I don't get the resource error in my browser console
3. Tried to learn more hogan and typeahead options to look for other options.  Not sure if something like a pre-render or setting default "local" values would help?

Thanks,

-Chris

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is your `self.userImgUrl` is not the same `userBlankImgUrl` used in your template - if this is intentional it's not clear from your posted snippets.

However, at some point your scripts are outputting the template *without* running it through your template object's `render()` method. The bad request is caused by the src attribute for the/an image tag litterally being "{{userBlankImgUrl}}". I'm guessing you're testing your app on a local server, so the address it looks up is `http://localhost/.../{{userBlankImgUrl}}` (unless the ### in your question isn't just you shortening/hiding the path and it really is requesting from localhost:####/%7B%7BuserBlankImgUrl%7D%7D - either way the problem (or at least part of it) is the same).

Hogan.js removes any undefined handlebar'd variables that appear in templates it renders:

```
var template = Hogan.compile(
    '<img class="quarc-avatar-list-item" src="{{undefinedVariable}}" />'
);
console.log( template.render({var1: "Test", var2: "Again"}) );
```

Will output to console:

```
<img class="quarc-avatar-list-item" src="" />
```

If anything appears in the src attribute or in the place of any `{{templateVar}}` where a `null` or `undefined` value was given then you know your template was outputted without going through the proper render method.